# Iteration count in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of tuples l, and I do something like this:

```
for (a,b) in l:
     do something with a,b, and the index of (a,b) in l
```

Is there an easy way to get the index of (a,b)? I can use the index method of list, but what if (a,b) is not unique? I can also iterate on the indexes in the first place, but its cumbersome. Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(l):
    # i will be the index of (a, b) in l
```

Answer (score 16):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,(a,b) in enumerate(l):
   ... # `i` contains the index
```